Custom Authorize attribute that checks if user has a particular username or is in roles
How can I make an AuthorizeAttribute that checks if user is in string containing groups and usernames. I've tried the following but it does not work.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AuthorizeRoleUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRoleUserAttribute(params string[] rolesUsers)
    {

        Roles = string.Join(",", 
            rolesUsers
                .Select(
                    r => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[r] ?? throw new Exception($"AppSettings '{r}' is not defined in Web.config")
                )
            );
        Users = string.Join(",",
            rolesUsers
                .Select(
                    r => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[r] ?? throw new Exception($"AppSettings '{r}' is not defined in Web.config")
                )
            );

    }
}

rolesUsers is a constant that maps to a AppSetting key which contains a string of comma(,) delimited Group names and User names.
Example 1: <add key="Test" value="GroupName1, domain\username1, GroupName2, domain\username2" />
What I also find confusing is that, when you call IsInRole() method on IPrincipal it works even if you have supplied a username.
Example 2: In some method in a controller if you call User.IsInRole("domain\\username1") returns TRUE if user is the specified username. Shouldn't it return FALSE as it should check only for roles? But if you call the same method User.IsInRole("domain\\username1") in some View it does not work (as expected).
